# Converting polygon values to a vector grid using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, vector-grid

What is the best way of converting a value from irregularly shaped poylgons to a polygon grid using PostGIS? I have a set of polygons that look like this:

[image]

and I would like to overlay a grid on these polygons, and assign values from the polygon to the grid value, proportional to the area of the polygon that intersects the grid. For example, where a grid intersects more than one polygon, I want to use the fraction of each polygon area that intersects with the gridcell to proportionally calculate the value.

[image]

My approach for doing this is as follows. Assuming each polygon has a value X_i and an area A_i, I calculate the density using D_i = X_i / A_i. Then, for each gridcell, I multiply the fraction of the polygon area that intersects that gridcell by the appropriate density value. I think this approach is satisfactory but I have not figured out a way of abstracting it so that it is easier for me to do this regularly.

I am curious to learn if there is a better way to do this, if there is a term for this process and if there is a function that exists to perform a calculation of this type.

Comment: I had a similar question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31108/area-weighted-rasterising-of-polygon-data which I solved using whuber's suggestion

Comment: hmm, interesting. I've done this before using rasters, but I feel like the vector-intersection approach is more accurate. I feel like a vector 'gridfying' function could be a worthy endeavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches: vector-based and raster-based. The former is more accurate, and the later is generally faster but much more complicated.

## Vector approach

Use the fraction of area overlap between each polygon and grid cell to weight the values. Say you have a `grid` (e.g. [created this way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/how-to-create-a-regular-polygon-grid-in-postgis/16390#16390)), and an irregular `poly` with values in `val`. To determine `val` on `grid`:

```
SELECT g.gid, g.row, g.col, count(distinct p.gid) as num_poly,
  sum(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(g.geom, p.geom)) / ST_Area(g.geom) * p.val) AS grid_val
FROM grid g
LEFT JOIN poly p ON ST_Intersects(g.geom, p.geom)
GROUP BY g.gid, g.row, g.col;
```

This query will take a while there are many tens of thousands of `grid` cells (i.e. 100 × 100, or more).

## Raster approach

The idea behind this method is if you rasterise values from an irregular polygon, you get the values. However, the rasterisation methods are limited, as [they don't consider the area fraction of polygons within each pixel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31108/area-weighted-rasterising-of-polygon-data). So you will need to modify this approach by rasterising at a finer resolution than desired, then generalise the refined raster to the desired resolution. The accuracy of this method increases with a finer initial raster resolution.

I can add more details to this method, but it is much more complicated. I did this approach first with [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) with files in a shell, then I moved the logic to GDAL/Python using [gdal.RasterizeLayer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31658/1872).

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. I grouped by `gid` and `geom`. I'm trying to understand the logic behind the `LEFT JOIN poly p ON ST_Intersects(g.geom, p.geom)` though. Is it like a true/false condition for relating the geometries?

Comment: yup, it finds each polygon (1 or more) that intersect with each grid cell

Comment: I forgot to say, it does return this warning message when running `NOTICE:  geometry_gist_joinsel called with incorrect join type`. I can't tell if this is a significant or not.

Comment: you can probably [safely] ignore it. It happens when there are no overlaps on the grid. If an `INNER JOIN` is used, the notice should go away, but you will see fewer rows (where there are no overlaps on the grid).